# How to make a struct variable null

Tags: c++, struct

How I can make a struct variable with null value?

```
struct student 
{
    char name[20];
    int id;
}; 
 
int main() 
{
    student std;
    cin >> std.name;
    cin >> std.id;
    // Now I want to make std null
}
```

Comment: Do not name your variable `std`

Comment: Grab a proper C++ book,  (structs) or classes do not have reference semantics like Java or C#.  If you want a nullable type, use `std::optional`, avoid unnecessary pointers.

Comment: Maybe if you guys stop complaining and try to help OP instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you mean by "null". A pointer can be null. But your class is not a pointer. A character can be the null terminator. But your class is not a character. You haven't defined what a "null" student is.

So, what do you mean when you want the variable to be "null"? Do you perhaps want the variable to optionally not contain an instance of `student`? There is a class template for just that use case in the standard library: `std::optional`. An "optional" that doesn't contain an object is said to be "empty" rather than "null".

Answer (score 0):

You may dynamically allocate it:

```
 struct student 
 {
     char name[20];
     int id;
 }; 
 
  int main() 
  {
    auto std = new student();
    cin>>std->nane;
    cin>>std->id;
    
    // ...

    std = nullptr;

    // ...

    return 0;
  }
```

It is however, recommended that you `delete` it first.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "null" you mean, empty all the values inside the struct or just make it `0`:

```
    #include <algorithm>

    //...your code

    std::fill(std.name, std.name + 20, 0);
    std.id = 0;
```

Or

```
   #include <cstring>

    //...your code

   std::memset(&std, 0, sizeof(std));
```

And if you meant "destroying" the variable, you don't have to do it yourself because when you reach `}`, your `std` will automatically be destroyed.